Follow up after PhD Position Interview
So I applied for a PhD position in engineering at TU/Eindhoven and was invited by the PI immediately after a day for a first interview. I gave the interview and the PI said that she would let me know. Now it has been three weeks and there has been no further contact from her. Should I send her a follow up email stating that I would appreciate any kind of feedback even if I have been rejected? The website of the university also explicitly states that even if candidates are rejected after interviews, they are contacted and given a review and feedback of their performance.

It’s too early. They might still be interviewing other candidates, they might be getting in touch with referees or going through HR processes, or it might be that they have made an offer to another candidate and are waiting to see whether it is accepted before they get back to other candidates. Wait a few more weeks.

In the Netherlands, candidates are either interviewed on a rolling basis until the deadline passes (which seems to be your case) or all interview invites are only sent once the deadline has passed. If the deadline for the applications has not passed, then they are likely still interviewing other candidates.
In either case, wait a couple of more weeks before sending a follow-up email.
